# React Component not working in production

Tags: reactjs, amazon-s3, redux, create-react-app

When I deploy my app I am having some problems.

In development everything is working perfectly

[image]

But, in production the data is not showing up.

After some tests, I realized that the problem is with the component **TabsComponent**, when I get rid of it everything is working. Do you have any idea how can I fix this problem?

https://serverlessapps.info/
[image]

Currently:

・Using React Redux and create react app

・Getting the data from a JSON file

・Storing AWS S3.

You can clone the repo from  https://github.com/Alfrex92/serverlessapps

What can I do?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

on your `package.json` added this line `"homepage": "http://localhost/",`
if you did upload your app in a sub folder on your server"homepage": `"http://localhost/foldername"`

then run : `npm run build`
I just test it on my localhost and it working

upload it like this dont change to `"homepage": "http://yoursite.com/"`

this is how your root directory should look like

```
httdocs
  |
  |-static
  |
  |-index.html
  |-serviceworker.js
```

Comment: not working, I added to my package.json : "name": "serverlessapp",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "homepage": "http://serverlessapps.info/", any other solution?

Comment: i will download your package on my local host and let you know in few minute, did the production build work on your local host ?

Comment: Still not working. 1) added "homepage":"http://localhost/" 2) added "scripts" 3) i ran npm i npm-run-all --save, (I couldn't use npm run build, because it has a lot of errors)

Comment: remove the script , keep your old script , that wierd i did try it and it working on my local host and with the production build

Comment: i just test it and it working , i cant know if the app is working proprely

Comment: I just realized that if I get rid of CSS the data is being displayed, any idea? help :)

Comment: After some tests, I realized that the problem is with  <TabsComponent />, when I get rid of it everything is working. Do you have any idea what I can do? help :D